# GRANT Permissions seem not to work on a VIEW

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following view (called `view3`)

[image]

I created a role and granted it `SELECT` and `UPDATE` rights just on two columns.

```
CREATE ROLE Testrole
GRANT SELECT (Doc_ID, [Total Attentions]) ON view3 TO Testrole
```

Then I assigned the role to a user (`test`) already created

```
ALTER ROLE Testrole ADD MEMBER test
```

But when the transaction checking if all is ok is executed, all the columns are shown instead of the two required (the same image above).

This is the script

```
CREATE LOGIN logtest
    WITH PASSWORD = 'logtest'

CREATE USER test 
    FOR LOGIN logtest

CREATE ROLE Testrole
GRANT SELECT (Doc_ID, [Total Attentions]) ON view3 TO Testrole
ALTER ROLE Testrole ADD MEMBER test


SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    EXECUTE AS USER = 'test'

    SELECT * /*This should give an error*/
        FROM view3

    SELECT Doc_ID, [Total Attentions] /*This should work just fine*/
        FROM view3

    REVERT

ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRANT permissions are cumulative. These symptoms suggest that view-level (all columns) permissions exist, inherited from this or other roles.  Run the query below to see if this is the case.

```
SELECT
      permission_name
    , OBJECT_NAME(major_id) AS ObjectName
    , CASE WHEN c.name IS NULL THEN 'All Columns' ELSE c.name END AS ColumnName
    , USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id) AS Gratee
FROM sys.database_permissions AS p
LEFT JOIN sys.columns AS c ON 
    c.object_id = p.major_id
    AND c.column_id = p.minor_id
WHERE
    major_id = OBJECT_ID(N'view3');
```

Comment: I ran it and it shows:
`permission_name: SELECT

Objectname: view3

ColumnName: All Columns

Grantee: test`

That suggests that somehow I granted to `test` SELECT privilege to all columns? How can that be possible if I haven't explicitly done that? How can that be fixed (I mean, constraint the SELECT or UPDATE privilege not to all columns)?.

Comment: By putting `REVOKE SELECT ON view3 FROM test` and executing all again the problem persists.

Comment: Try executing `REVOKE SELECT ON view3 FROM test`, verify `SELECT` by user test fails due to no permissions, and then grant column permissions again. I would expect only a `SELECT` with the granted columns will succeed.

Comment: Now all works (:. I had to revoke the `SELECT` privilege from the `Testrole`, then grant it him again and execute the transaction. Maybe I had slipped up with the order of execution. Thanks you (: